# Live display of variables during MATLAB simulation

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a simulation which has numerous iterations. There are variable matrices whose values I would like to monitor while the simulation is happening. What are good ways of doing this?

Comment: `disp(your_variable)` within each iteration? Or, if you only want them displayed every say `10` iterations: `if mod(iter_index, 10)==0, disp(your_variable); end`

Comment: Actually I was thinking if I can see them on a fixed window instead of the command window. On command window lots of traffic is there.

Comment: That can be done using a `text` object in a figure, and updating the `string` property of the object. Don't forget `drawnow` to flush the event queue so that the updated text is actually shown

Answer (score 1):

I have two tools that I regularly use for something like this.

**1. Iterative output that erases with each iteration**

This works well for an optimization where you have a scalar function output you want to monitor.

Before my `while` loop, I'll define `screenOut = [];` and an output formula in `screenOutFormat`. In my loop after the computation has happened for that iteration, I'll put something like

```
if iter <=2
  bspace = [];
else
  bspace = repmat('\b', [1 length(screenOut)]);
end
screenOut = sprintf(screenOutFormat, iter, estimatedValue);
fprintf([bspace screenOut]);
```

This way you get to see the starting point and each iteration without destroying your command window history.

**2. Dynamic updates to a figure**

This works well if you have something you can plot.

Before the loop begins, set up a plot with

```
figH = figure();
progPlot = plot(Y);
```

Then with each iteration you can do

```
progPlot.YData = Y;
drawnow();
```

This way you continue plotting the estimate you care about.

---

If you have a matrix that you care about, I'd recommend picking off the elements that you're really interested in and using #1. But if there's something more useful you can plot, #2 is usually more interesting to watch during long estimation/simulation routines.